# Error in backup query of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-backup

I have a database in SQL Server and I want to create backup from it to a shared folder.

just one of the network users has permissions to access to this folder.

I have written a code to log on this user at the middle of my program and then execute Backup command.

This code worked all ever I want to access to my folder. But now I receive this error:

> Cannot open backup device 'folder path with backup file
>   name'.Operating system error5(failed to retrieve text for this error, Reason: 1815)
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally

Comment: What happened between *'This code worked…'* and *'But now…'*?

Comment: Check the SQL Server error logs through Management Studio and see what is there.  There will be more information regarding your backup failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user account that the SQL Server is running as must have permissions to the backup location. The user account running the script is irrelevant in this situation, since it's the SQL Server process performing the file operations.

If the SQL Server is running as NETWORK SERVICE or SYSTEM, then in a domain environment you can grant the DOMAIN\COMPUTERNAME$ account access to the file share. Otherwise, this would be the user listed under SQL Server Configuation Manager → SQL Server Services → Properties for "SQL Server" → Log On tab.

Comment: thanks, for your answer.yes my SQL Server is installed on server and i access to it from clients.but i can not understand completely what did you mean by DOMAIN\COMPUTERNAME$ ?

Comment: If you are running a Windows domain, then not only do users have domain accounts but also every computer which is joined to the domain has an account called COMPUTERNAME$ (substitute the actual name of the computer, of course). If your domain name is DOMAIN, then the account name of the computer is DOMAIN\COMPUTERNAME$, and any service running as NETWORK SERVICE accesses the network using this account.

Comment: thanx, i got it exactly. but another question is which computer should i grant to access to shared folder? server or client? Excuse me for my beginner questions.

Comment: To create the backup, the server needs access to the file share. That's the computer that will be writing the backup file.